# Broken Pipe exception when tried to stream mp3 stream from local server to android mediaplayer

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am trying to stream mp3 stream from my local http server indeed hosted on my phone to android media player.When local server gets the new socket , it starts writing some http headers followed by mp3 stream. but mediaplayer socket is throwing "Broken pipe" exception.Wat may be the issue causing this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instrument the server with logging